# How do I overload () operator with two parameters; like (3,5)?

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading

I have a mathematical matrix class. It contains a member function which is used to access any element of the class.

```
template<class T>
class Matrix
{
    public:
        // ...
        void SetElement(T dbElement, uint64_t unRow, uint64_t unCol);
        // ...
};

template <class T>
void Matrix<T>::SetElement(T Element, uint64_t unRow, uint64_t unCol)
{
    try
    {
        // "TheMatrix" is define as "std::vector<T> TheMatrix"
        TheMatrix.at(m_unColSize * unRow + unCol) = Element;
    }
    catch(std::out_of_range & e)
    {
        // Do error handling here
    }
}
```

I'm using this method in my code like this:

```
// create a matrix with 2 rows and 3 columns whose elements are double
Matrix<double> matrix(2, 3);
// change the value of the element at 1st row and 2nd column to 6.78
matrix.SetElement(6.78, 1, 2);
```

This works well, but I want to use operator overloading to simplify things, like below:

```
Matrix<double> matrix(2, 3);
matrix(1, 2) = 6.78;    // HOW DO I DO THIS?
```

Comment: Just a little typo: `template <class T>`

Comment: Why not just overload operator[]?

Comment: @DeadMG: because `operator[]` only takes one parameter?

Comment: @jalf: Can easily be chained though, like, matrix[1][2], like a regular array.

Comment: @DeadMG: Probably, but it's way easier to overload `operator()`.

Comment: I'd think overloading operator() would violate the principle of least surprise...  Why is (x,y) better than [x][y] other than typing a bit more?

Comment: @JimR: I'd say the principle of least surprise states pretty clearly "you should be able to index into an iterator", perhaps with the addendum "every other matrix class ever written allows this". So yes, defining `operator()` is perfectly fine. It's what the user almost certainly expects. (And it's less typing than having to define chainable `operator[]`s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return a reference to the element in the overloaded `operator()`.

```
template<class T>
class Matrix
{
    public:
        T& operator()(uint64_t unRow, uint64_t unCol);

        // Implement in terms of non-const operator
        // to avoid code duplication (legitimate use of const_cast!)
        const T&
        operator()(uint64_t unRow, uint64_t unCol) const
        {
            return const_cast<Matrix&>(*this)(unRow, unCol);
        }
};

template<class T>
T&
Matrix<T>::operator()(uint64_t unRow, uint64_t unCol)
{
    // return the desired element here
}
```

Comment: In both `operator()` methods you should return reference to actual element. Alex forgot to write that. The first one (without `conts`) is used in assignment, the second one is used when getting value from matrix.

Comment: Why did we define two different methods? Couldn't we do it with a single method which returns a reference?

Comment: The forwarding version is broken, it returns a reference to a temporary variable.

Comment: @Pawel: No, the first version is used for all access (read and write to matrix) if the matrix is non-const.  @hkBattousai: Which method do you think is redundant?  They return two different types, one is `T&` and the other is `const T&`.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, you're right. 
@hkBattousai: If the `Matrix` is `const` and you'll call `operator()` there will be method with `const` called. Without it you wouldn't be able to get elements from constant `Matrix` objects with `operator()`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, well spotted. Corrected.